# UISlider maximum values adjustments

Tags: iphone, uislider

I am having three sliders and these shows the percentages for different elements what i need the max value of all is 100 (a+b+c=100).

Now these all are dependent to each other and helps in making a pie chart.

currently all can set to max value that is 100.

how can make this dependency and max value logically.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In methods where you handle your sliders changes adjust maximum values for all sliders depending on current ones, e.g.:

```
- (void) sliderChanged:(UISlider*)sender{
    slider1.maximumValue = 100 - slider2.value - slider3.value;
    // etc
}
```

**Edit:** Adjusting maximum value may indeed lead to not behaviour. Instead to ensure that the sum does not exceed 100 you can manually adjust slider's value if it is more than desired:

```
- (void) sliderChanged:(UISlider*)sender{
    //sender is slider1
    sender.value = MIN(sender.value, 100 - slider2.value - slider3.value);
    // etc
}
```

Comment: this shows an odd combination, one slider shows 60 at position other shows 20 at that position because of max value can be stop the moving of sliders rather than setting max values.

Comment: Ok thank you, setting max value according to other is good but if i will get the solution that implies stop moving of the sliders according to max value that is 100 rather than setting max values then i want to go that one.Thank you very much.